# How to accept licences to install SDK packages

Tags: android, angular, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to convert an existing Angular application to Android by using cordova and Android Studio. I'm stuck at the last step of a guide to covert, where I need to accept `platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28` in order to proceed.

I know there's already answers where you should simply use:

`yes | sdkmanager --licenses` 
in order to accept all licenses, but I couldn't find any thread where to put that command.

I've never used Android Studio before. I've managed to find SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This command should be run on a Bash CLI

Answer (score 0):

try this cmd to install sdk, cmake and so on:

```
  echo y | ./tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "ndk-bundle" "cmake;3.6.4111459" --include_obsolete "extras;google;m2repository"  \
```